# How to use GitHub Actions to Auto Publish Typescript Package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, npm, github-actions

I am using GitHub actions to auto-publish my [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-schema-cli) whenever I push the code to master branch. The problem is in my `.gitignore` I have added the `/dist/` folder. So when I push the code to cloud, it ignores the `dist` folder and I want only dist folder to be published. How do I do this?

I tried using `npm install` and `npm run build` to create a `dist` folder and in the cloud and then publish the package but it doesn't work. It doesn't create a compiled version.
The only solution I see is I remove `/dist/` from `.gitignore` and upload it to the cloud but is there any other way that I can ignore dist and also auto-publish it to npm using Github Actions?

Here are my `.yml` file

```
name: NPM Publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  release:
    name: Pubish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: ⏬ checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.1
      - name:  Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1.4.2
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org
      - name:  Publish
        run: npm publish --access public
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to build it before publishing or add a pre-publish script in your package.json file.

i.e:

```
  - name: Build
    run: npm run build
  - name:  Publish
    run: npm publish --access public
```

Or
In package.json

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
  ...
  "prepublish": "npm run build",
}
```

The reason why it's not building is that it doesn't have the node_modules so you also need to install them and ideally use cache.

So you would need to add to your yaml file before building.

```
- name: install
  run: npm install
```

or if you are using a lock file, (not ideal for packages)

```
- name: install
  run: npm ci
```

Please try to also use a cache instead of overloading npm registry.

Comment: And this will create `dist` folder in the repo as well, right? Is it possible if GitHub Action deleted that dist folder once the package is published?
Also, do I need to add that `npm install` if I am using `prepublish`?

Comment: It will not create a dist folder in your repo at all.
And yes you need `npm install` or `npm ci` in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After i did everything written here, action doesn't add dist/ folder to npm. Solution was create .npmignore file and add inside tsconfig.json and all ts files(*.ts)